# Ubuntu Freezing problem

Tags: hp

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTC with HP having following configuration:

```
Memory:-11.7 GiB
Processor: Intel Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 V2@3.10GHz x 4
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe(LLVM 3.4,256 bits)
OS type: 64 bit
Disk: 980.2 GB
```

As, I have installed Virtual Machine on my system so after every 1 hour or 1.5 hours the OS freezes or the Virtual Machine gets automatically shut down.

Could anyone tell me because of which reason it happen??

Comment: How much RAM did you put for your Virtual?

Comment: I am putting 2 Gb Ram